# About the continuity of the integral on the boundary of a ball of a $H^1$ function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I’m considering a $H^1$ function u on a open domain D. Is the integral:

$$ \int_{\partial B_r(x)} u \hspace{2pt}dH^{n-1}$$

continuous with respect to x?

I tried to prove that it’s differential by showing that the derivative can be written as the integration:

$$ \int_{\partial B_r(x)} Du \hspace{2pt}dH^{n-1}$$

But it’s just right a.e. From which we can deduce that it’s continuous a.e.. Could we prove that it’s continuous everywhere?

---

To show it’s right a.e., we start by considering a sequence of smooth functions approaching u in $H^1$. For each $u_n$, the derivative is:

$$ \int_{\partial B_r(x)} Du_n \hspace{2pt}dH^{n-1}$$

And it approaches

$$ \int_{\partial B_r(x)} Du \hspace{2pt}dH^{n-1}$$

Comment: How do you define the integral of $Du$ (a mere $L^2$ function) over an $n-1$-dimensional set?

Comment: @Jose27 Well, as it’s L2, we can just use fubini here to define it a.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it's not clear to me that, **fixing** $r>0$, you can conclude that $\int_{\partial B_r(x)} Du(y)\, dH^{n-1}(y)$ is well defined, even for a.e. $x$: Fubini (and polar coordinates) gives that this integral is finite, for fixed $x$, for a.e. $r>0$, but this is not the same.

On the other hand, the continuity of your function follows without such arguments. Notice that for $y\in \partial B_r(x)$, the vector $n(y)= \frac{y-x}{r}$ is the exterior unit normal to $B_r(x)$ at $y$. So we can write, using the divergence theorem,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y)dH^{n-1}(y) & = \int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y) \dfrac{y-x}{r}\cdot n(y)\, dH^{n-1}(y)\\
& = \int_{B_r(x)} \left[ \nabla u(y)\cdot \dfrac{y-x}{r} +  \dfrac{nu(y)}{r}  \right]\, dH^{n-1}(y),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and this last term is continuous by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: For the first one, I’ve edited the question with the sketch of my proof. And, I do believe your proof is right, thank you for your help!